# Show divs in reverse order

Tags: html, css

I have several sibling `div`s with `position: fixed; display: table; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;`. In fact, they are message boxes. They are generated by third-party ASP.NET control, and I am unable to change their order in ASP.NET file.  But I want to change their overlapping order to reversed: first declared is displayed on top. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child if you know the length of your divs
Let us say you have div length is 4 you can use z-index like this

```
div:last-child{z-index: 4}
div:nth-child(3){z-index: 3}
div:nth-child(2){z-index: 2}
div:first-child{z-index: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/mooreinteractive/ffh5t88g/9/

Basically, I am converting the list of divs into an array, then using the array's .reverse() method. The weird part, is converting it back from an array to HTML...

The first part, converting it to an array, and clearing the original divs from the DOM:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.msg');
var divsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(divs, 0);
document.querySelector('#cont').innerHTML = '';
```

Then, reverse the array, and convert it back to HTML using the array's .map() method:

```
divsArr.reverse().map(function(htmlObj){
    document.querySelector('#cont').appendChild(htmlObj);
});
```

You can probably make it a bit more cleaner, and this assumes they are inside a parent div of id="cont", so you'll have to adjust that of course, and how you clear the original divs.